# Struct initialization of derived struct with a templated base type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use struct initialization on a derived from template struct. The code goes something like this:

```
template <class Derived>
struct Event{
//the level of access on the ctor has nothing to do with the problem
//protected:
//    Event() = default;
};

struct MoveEvent: Event<MoveEvent>{
    int x, y;
};


int main(){
    //how do I make this work?
  //MoveEvent event = {.x =5, .y = 4};
}
```

I thought it might have something to do with CTRP, but changing `Event<MoveEvent>` to `Event<int>` yields the same problem. Furthermore, I thought it was an issue with POD, but `std::is_pod` returns `true` for `MoveEvent`. So what's the problem here? Why can't I use struct initialization?

Comment: C++ doesn't support C99 designated initializers.

Comment: But I am using C++11.

Comment: @user975989 It doesn't matter, that is a C feature, not a C++ feature

Comment: Did you try `MoveEvent event = {.5, 4};` already? Also put the verbatim error messages you get in your question please.

Comment: Ah. So the problem lies in the inheritance, since a non inheriting `MoveEvent` works.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [that won't work either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983539/why-can-i-not-brace-initialize-a-struct-derived-from-another-struct)

Comment: There's the answer, thank you.

Comment: @m.s. THX for the insight! Learn something new everyday, keeps the Alzheimer's disease away ;-) (there's an age when you don't care so much about your teeth health, or vitamin supply so much, but rather keep your brain going)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only do aggregate initialization on aggregates. An aggregate is, from [dcl.init.aggr]:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or
>   protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes (Clause 10)**, and no virtual functions (10.3).

`MoveEvent` is not an aggregate. Thus, you will have to add a constructor:

```
template <class Derived>
struct Event {
};

struct MoveEvent: Event<MoveEvent> {
    MoveEvent(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
    int x, y;
};


int main() {
    MoveEvent event{5, 4}; // NOW this is fine
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use this syntax for a couple reasons, firstly that "designated initializers" are a C feature, [not a C++ feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99)

```
MoveEvent event = {.x = 5, .y = 4};
```

Secondly, you cannot use aggregate initialization for a derived class, because as soon as you introduce inheritance, you [no longer have a POD aggregate type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983539/why-can-i-not-brace-initialize-a-struct-derived-from-another-struct).

Your best best is to define a constructor for the derived class

```
struct MoveEvent: Event<MoveEvent>
{
    MoveEvent(int _x, int _y) : x{_x}, y{_y} {}
    int x, y;
};
```

Then you can do this

```
MoveEvent event{5, 4};
```