# How to add common functionalities to structs by way of inheritance without having to explicitly initialize the base struct?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have some structs that all have some common functionalities that I've put in an templated base class (here `Foo<int>`)

```
template<int I>
struct Foo
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo: " << I << '\n'; }
};

struct Bar : Foo<1>
{
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

Now when I initialize any of them I have to do it like so:

```
Bar b{{}, 1, 2};
```

And I would like to be able to do it like so:

```
Bar b{1, 2};
```

And also without the boilerplate of having to write a constructor.
Is there some solution to this problem?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793983/struct-initialization-of-derived-struct-with-a-templated-base-type), however, this was over 7 years ago, so I was wondering if there were any developments since then.
Also, that question is marked duplicate of a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983539/why-can-i-not-brace-initialize-a-struct-derived-from-another-struct), however this one is slightly different, as the base struct is not empty.
In addition, I'm not really trying to accomplish anything other than adding functionality to some structures, in a more declarative way, rather than repeating the definitions of all the common methods in each of them. So any solution that achieves that, by circumventing inheritance (apart from macros ideally ;D) would work as well.

Comment: With your constraints it's not possible. You want it to stay an aggregate (no written constructor), so you must initialize with the aggregate syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use designated initializers here:

```cpp
Bar b{.i = 1, .j = 2};
```

You can also make the aggregate `struct { int i; int j; }` the first thing inherited from. Here are two ways you can make that happen:

```cpp
template<int I>
struct Foo
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo: " << I << '\n'; }
};

struct BarBase {
    int i;
    int j;
};

struct Bar : BarBase, Foo<1> {};

Bar x{{.i = 1, .j = 2}};
Bar y{1, 2};
```

```cpp
// This way also allows you to access the base.
// A common pattern for mixins, which is what Foo is
template<typename Base, int I>
struct Foo : Base
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo: " << I << '\n'; }
};

struct BarBase {
    int i;
    int j;
};

using Bar = Foo<BarBase, 1>;

Bar x{{.i = 1, .j = 2}};
Bar y{1, 2};
```

Comment: thats a lot of stuff to add to avoid typing {}

Comment: @​ServeLaurijssen The question makes it seem like `Foo` is the base class for many different classes. Also `Bar{{}, 1, 2};` is error prone if you use it in many places since it might accidentally initialize the first member to `0` if a class didn't happen to have an empty base class