# Using initializer list for a struct with inheritance

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I have a struct that I'd like to initialize using an initializer list

```
struct Parent{};

struct Child : private Parent {
    int b;
};

int main() {
    Child c{ 1 };
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at other questions I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983539/why-can-i-not-brace-initialize-a-struct-derived-from-another-struct/16983926#16983926) that states that it should be possible in c++17.

However when I try the above snippet in `VS2017` I get

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'child'
```

Is there any way to utilize this new feature?

Comment: With little modification, it works with gcc: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d89101d38847de7a). Remove `private` and initialize base `Parent`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With inheritance, each base class subobject of the aggregate is initialized like a member. So to aggregate initialization, `Child` has two subobjects: `Parent`, and `i`. So you need two initializers in your braced-init-list:

```
Child c{ {}, 1 };
```

Also, in order for `Child` to be an aggregate, all subobjects must be *public*. So you can't have private base classes.

Of course, this assumes that Visual Studio implements the feature correctly. VS2017 15.5 is not C++17 compliant, but 15.7 supports this.

Comment: apparently it doesn't implement it. At least not yet. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/08/11/c17-features-and-stl-fixes-in-vs-2017-15-3/

Comment: @Bomaz I'm not seeing it in there, could you at least give me something to search for.

Comment: @JonathanMee: It's called "Extended aggregate initialization", and it's listed (on that page) as "No". Note that VS15.7 supports this.

Comment: Heh... Well I'd typed up an answer extending yours before I saw you commented back. Shouldaknown you're too involved to leave an incomplete answer. Thank you for improving +1. Also I'll leave my answer just cause I went to all the trouble of typing it. But I've added the source link to your answer lest anyone think I figured it out on my own :)

Answer (score 7):

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) has introduced an [Extension to Aggregate Initialization(P0017R1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r1.html) which provides for the construction of a derived instance while still explicitly initializing the base class:

```
struct base { int a1, a2; };
struct derived : base { int b1; };

derived d1{{1, 2}, 3};      // full explicit initialization
derived d1{{}, 1};          // the base is value initialized
```

Thus using the "Extension to Aggregate Initialization" you'll want to use the code: `Child c{ {}, 1 }` as mentioned in [Nicol Bolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47334014/2642059) again with his caveat that you'd need to use `public` *not* `private` inheritance to do aggregate initialization at all.

Unfortunately [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) did not support P0017R1 [until version 15.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2017). So it may be necessary to upgrade your Visual Studio to accomplish this.

---

If that's not possible, and you're able to get by without polymorphisim, you can temporarily define:

```
struct Child {
    Parent a;
    int b;
};
```

Which would allow you to use the consistent code: `Child c{ {}, 1 }` now and whenever you change back to inheritance after upgrading to 15.7.