# C++ Call default constructor for Struct and its inherited members

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14

I'd like to be able to initialize an object with the following syntax in C++14:

```
const auto data1 = DataOne{1, 2, 3};
const auto data2 = DataTwo{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
const auto data3 = DataThree{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Which gives me the following error message:

> ```
> error msg `error: no matching function for call to ‘DataThree::DataThree(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’`
> ```

With the types defined as:

```
struct DataOne
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct DataTwo : DataOne
{
    int d;
    int e;
};

struct DataThree : DataTwo
{
    int f;
    int g;
};
```

I dont want to use the *struct in struct* method because then I will need to call params through double or triple dots which I dont want to use because all the members are equal important and it will look bad to read.

Comment: So what's the error message? Which C++ standard can you use?

Comment: Perfectly valid C++17, there is nothing to reproduce.

Comment: A relevant question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983539/why-can-i-not-brace-initialize-a-struct-derived-from-another-struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of C++17, the syntax you wish for is valid:

```
const auto data3 = DataThree{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0baba32107d37cb5)

Before that, aggregate initialization would be illegal per `[dcl.init.aggr]/1`:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).