# List-Initialization of a Subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, aggregate, list-initialization

I want to initialize a class B that is a subclass of A by list-initialization (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

However, it does not work like this:

```
struct A {
   int x;
};

struct B : public A {
};

int main()
{
   A a{ 1 }; // compiles
   B b{ 2 }; // doesn't compile
}
```

Is there a way to initialize instances of B through list-initialization?

Essentially, I want to intitialize an instance of B without declaring any constructor.

Comment: Do you want to keep `B` as being an aggregate?

Comment: @NathanOliver I would prefer so. Essentially, I want to initialize the subclass with values without declaring any constructor. I updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: "*Is there a way to initialize instances of B through list-initialization?*" Use c++17.

Comment: Dupe: [Why can I not brace initialize a struct derived from another struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983539/why-can-i-not-brace-initialize-a-struct-derived-from-another-struct)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using a C++ compiler that compiles your program based on the C++ Standard before the C++ 17 Standard.

Before the C++ 17 Standard aggregates may not contain base classes.

So use the compiler option that sets at least the specification of the C++ 17 Standard.

According to the C++ 14 Standard (8.5.1 Aggregates)

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
> constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
> (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
> (10.3).

Starting from the C++ 17 Standard aggregates are allowed to have base classes (11.6.1 Aggregates)

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 12) with
>
> (1.1) — no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors (15.1),
>
> (1.2) — no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 14),
>
> (1.3) — no virtual functions (13.3), and
>
> (1.4) — no virtual, private, or protected base classes (13.1).

Pay also attention to that there is a difference according to aggregates in the C++17 and the C++20 Standards. For example in C++ 17 you are allowed to declare a constructor for an aggregate with the specifier `default`.

That is this program

```
struct A {
   int x;
};

struct B : public A {
    B() = default;
};

int main()
{
   A a{ 1 }; 
   B b{ 2 }; 
}
```

is valid according to the C++ 17 Standard and is invalid according to the C++20 Standard.

But if you will declare the constructor with the specifier `explicit`

```
struct B : public A {
   explicit  B() = default;
};
```

then the program will not be valid even according to the C++ 17 Standard.

Comment: Apparently, the compiler developers and I agree that it should be possible to instantiate sublcasses like this :D thanks for the quick response, it worked!