# Struct inheritance, field initialization not allowed?

Tags: c++, c++14

In C++14, I'm deriving from a *struct*:

```
struct base {
  int i;
};

struct derived: base {};
```

I can initialize `base`:

```
base b{10};
```

But I can't do the same with `derived`:

```
derived d{10};
```

This is working in C++17, but with earlier compilers seems invalid. How can I initialize *base* fields from *derived*?

It seems the compiler is looking for the copy-constructor, which is obviously invalid here.

Comment: My guess is that in C++14, `derived` is not an aggregate, while in C++17 it is.

Comment: Dupe: [Changes in C++17 Aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786105/12002570)

Comment: Here is *exact dupe*: [List-Initialization of a Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73209232/list-initialization-of-a-subclass)

Comment: The question is focusing on *what to do with C++14*. Moreover, in case having more base members and derived members, writing n*m constructors for derived is overwhelming. Maybe move to template-based approach?